# Repeat index of a DataFrame for each unique element in a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way in which I can repeat every element of a index for a given MultiIndex unique element.

So, assuming I am using the following code to create a empty data just with the index:

```
df_x1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':np.linspace(1,4,4)}) 
df = pd.DataFrame(index = df_x1['x1'].values)
```

Now, I would like to create a multilevel indexing with the following data:

```
df_x2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2': np.linspace(0,2,3)})
```

Afterwards, I would like for each unique element of df_x2, set all the indexes in df_x1 as subindexes of df_2. So, finally, I would expect an empty dataframe with the results that resembles something like this:

```
0  1
   2
   3
   4
1  1
   2
   3
   4
2  1
   2
   3
   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for `MultiIndex` of all combinations:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_x2['x2'], df.index])
print (mux)
MultiIndex([(0.0, 1.0),
            (0.0, 2.0),
            (0.0, 3.0),
            (0.0, 4.0),
            (1.0, 1.0),
            (1.0, 2.0),
            (1.0, 3.0),
            (1.0, 4.0),
            (2.0, 1.0),
            (2.0, 2.0),
            (2.0, 3.0),
            (2.0, 4.0)],
           )
```

And then pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=mux)
```

Or if data in `df` are not empty and is necessary repeat rows add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df2 = df.reindex(mux, level=1)
print (df2)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 2.0), (0.0, 3.0), (0.0, 4.0), (1.0, 1.0), 
        (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 3.0), (1.0, 4.0), (2.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0), 
        (2.0, 3.0), (2.0, 4.0)]

print (df2.index)
MultiIndex([(0.0, 1.0),
            (0.0, 2.0),
            (0.0, 3.0),
            (0.0, 4.0),
            (1.0, 1.0),
            (1.0, 2.0),
            (1.0, 3.0),
            (1.0, 4.0),
            (2.0, 1.0),
            (2.0, 2.0),
            (2.0, 3.0),
            (2.0, 4.0)],
           )
```